# Scala pattern matching with Option type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to define a binary tree with the following definition:

```
  trait Node {
    val label: Int
  }
  case class BranchNode(override val label: Int, left: Option[Node], right: Option[Node]) extends Node
  case class LeafNode(override val label: Int) extends Node
```

and then define a simple `printTree` method using Scala's pattern matching as below:

```
  def printTree(aTree: Option[Node]): Unit = aTree match {
    case None => print(".")
    case Some(LeafNode(label)) => print(label)
    case Some(BranchNode(label, left, right)) => "{" + printTree(left) + label + printTree(right) + "}"
  }
```

The Intellij IDE warns me that the match may not be exhaustive. An `Option` can have `None` or `Some` as it's values. In case of `Option[Node]`, it can either be `Some(LeafNode)` or `Some(BranchNode)`. What other cases am I overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your trait isn't `sealed`, it is open for extension in different packages. IntelliJ is warning you of the future possibility that anyone extending this trait and forgetting to implement an additional `case` may cause a `MatchError`. If you want to limit it's extension, use:

```
sealed trait Node
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitely its a compiler warning, see below I'm breaking your code, by passing `printTree(Option(IWillBreakYou(2)))`

[image: match error]

```
      trait Node {
        val label: Int
      }
      case class BranchNode(override val label: Int, left: Option[Node], right: Option[Node]) extends Node
      case class LeafNode(override val label: Int) extends Node

      case class IWillBreakYou(override val label: Int) extends Node

      def printTree(aTree: Option[Node]): Unit = aTree match {
        case None => print(".")
        case Some(LeafNode(label)) => print(label)
        case Some(BranchNode(label, left, right)) => "{" + printTree(left) + label + printTree(right) + "}"
      }

      val leftNode = Option(LeafNode(2))
      val rightNode = Option(LeafNode(3))
      printTree(Option(BranchNode(1, leftNode, rightNode)))

      printTree(Option(IWillBreakYou(2))) //this will fail
```

The reason is since you are taking `Option[Node]` AND anybody can extend `Node` (within/outside of package unless protected) which you are not considering in your matches.

So, adding failsafe match `case _` would fix the future error.

```
def printTree(aTree: Option[Node]): Unit = aTree match {
        case None => print(".")
        case Some(LeafNode(label)) => print(label)
        case Some(BranchNode(label, left, right)) => "{" + printTree(left) + label + printTree(right) + "}"
        case _ => println("do nothing")
 }
```